# How to add "Cancel" button to "login" control of asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, authentication, asp.net-membership

Just as the title says, I have this model pop up box (using ajax ModalPopupExtender) that opens up when user clicks "Login", but the problem is that it can only be dismissed by Logging in. So I'd like to allow a "Cancel" button to this "Login" control so that if user clicks it, the dialog is dismissed.
I can handle the click event of that "Cancel" button and dismiss the dialog, but the problem is how do I add one?
I couldn't find any setting in Visual studio?
Any help?

edit: please read the comment, if you wanna suggest making a custom control.

Comment: I think you can template it. Then you can add any html, the downside is that you have to all the ordinary textboxes and stuff as well (with correct ID:s, username etc)

Comment: @MikaelHärsjö
Yeah I could, but I thought it would be better if there would be some way to achieve this by using asp.net Login control only, if I template it, just like you said, I'd have to configure everything and take the responsibility of validating not only the input, but then checking the authentication too. Soooo... Hoping there might be some way to do this by asp.net login control only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you don't want to use a template, I'd suggest that your best bet is going to be to subclass the login control and add your own extensions to it's markup.

You might want to look at the following:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1035097.aspx/1

http://www.dotnetspark.com/Forum/239-cancel-button-login-control.aspx